# What is the meaning of the Latin inscription on Anarch Peak's tomb?

Tags: novel, philip-k-dick

In Philip K. Dick's novel *Counter-Clock World*, the following inscription is said to be written on the Anarch's tomb:

> Sic igitur magni quoque circum moenia mundi
>   expugnata dabunt labem putresque ruinas.

What does it mean in English?

Comment: Google translation isn't much help: "So, then, around the walls of the world, too, of the great and rotten with the stain will be stormed and laid waste."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quote is by Lucretius. In the translation of W.H. Mallock:

**"So likewise the walls of the great universe assailed on all sides shall suffer decay, and fall into mouldering ruin."**

--Book ii 1144, 1145, [Lucretius on Life and Death: In the Metre of Omar Khayyam](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009YTLHZU)

Comment: Mallock's translation is easier to understand. Leonard's is more poetic.

Comment: @Gilles I agree with you, this translation is easier to uderstand.

Answer (score 7):

This is a quote from [Lucretius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucretius)'s [*De rerum natura*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_rerum_natura), near the end of [book II](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/lucretius/lucretius2.shtml) (lines 1144–1145).

In the [translation](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0131%3Abook%3D2%3Acard%3D1144) by [William Ellery Leonard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Ellery_Leonard):

> Thus, too, the ramparts of the mighty world
>   On all sides round shall taken be by storm,
>   And tumble to wrack and shivered fragments down.